# Как сделать, чтобы npm устанавливал модули в node_modules текущего проекта?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Находясь в **D:\nodejs\Project** прописываю в терминале (вебшторма) npm i express -s. Модуль устанавливается в **D:\nodejs\node_modules** (а мне нужно чтобы сохранилось в ***D:\nodejs\Project\node_modules***) и так как я пожелал, чтобы данные сохранились в package.json (через -s), мне ещё и выдало ошибку "**ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\nodejs\package.json'**". Как сделать, чтобы когда я находясь в папке \Project, прописывал npm i express, express устанавливался в текущую директорию, в папку node_modules?
Пробовал шаманить с NODE_PATH в свойствах компьютера, всё что там можно, чтобы например модули всегда ставились в папку \Project, а вот чтобы модули установились в директорию, в которой я нахожусь, я не знаю как сделать...
Очистил переустановил node.js, всё-равно не помогло... Помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, нужно было в текущей директории написать npm init, создать package.json и всё заработало.